# Trouble in session logout

Tags: jsp, session, servlets, session-variables, sessiontracking

I have read that there is the method logout() that we can use in servlets.
So,I am doing something like this

```
HttpSession sr=request.getSession();
sr.logout();
```

But this gives me an error that it cannot find the symbol logout();
Plz help.I want the user to logout and go to home page(home.jsp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no logout method exist in HttpSession

```
//This code will redirect to  homepage.jsp
 RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("homepage.jsp");
  rd.forward(request, response);
```

You can use `session.invalidate();` to invalidate the session

Comment: @saumyaraj  Yes it will delete everything in the session (attribute..etc).

Answer (score 1):

`HttpServletRequest` has a [logout](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#logout%28%29) method, but it assumes you are using the servlet way of doing security. It clears the security context, but won't clear your session.

If you just want to clear the session, do

```
HttpSession sr = request.getSession();
sr.invalidate();
```